# Dirty animation react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to animated a view with the `Animated` API of react native. No problem on ios, but I can't obtain a nice animation on android.

On ios:

[image: ios]

On android:

[image]

As you can see I receive a saccade on android.
Did I missed something?

Here is my component:

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react'
  import { Animated, View } from 'react-native'

  class Badge extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        scale: new Animated.Value(0)
      }
    }

    componentWillMount(nextProps) {
      Animated.sequence([
        Animated.timing(
          this.state.scale,
          {
            toValue: 1.3,
            duration: 200,
            useNativeDriver: true
          }
        ),
        Animated.timing(
          this.state.scale,
          {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: 400,
            useNativeDriver: true
          }
        )
      ]).start()
    }

    render() {
      const { container, text } = styles
      const containerAnimated = {...container, transform: [{scale: this.state.scale}]}

      return (
        <Animated.View style={containerAnimated}></Animated.View>
      )
    }

  }

  const styles = {
    container: {
      position: 'absolute',
      height: 50,
      width: 50,
      backgroundColor: 'pink'
    }
  }

  class App extends Component {

    render() {
      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <Badge />
        </View>
      )
    }

  }


  export default App
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried it in release mode ? My animations are not smooth at all in debug mode, but when I build my app in release they are smooth as butter

Comment: @AntoineGrandchamp the same :(

Comment: +++++++++++++++